# Esri ArcGIS extent finished rendering/downloading tiles notification

Tags: android, arcgis, esri

Is there a way to find that for current MapView extent fetching images and rendering them has finished?
Some kind of listener/delegate for this on Android/iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGIS Runtime Quartz, which is in beta now, check out [`GeoView.addDrawStatusChangedListener`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/beta/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/GeoView.html#addDrawStatusChangedListener(com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.DrawStatusChangedListener)). This appears to be a new capability in Runtime Quartz that is not available in Runtime 10.2.x.

Comment: Definitely I will have a look! Thanks!